# Source filtering not working on kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to exclude some field with [source filtering.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-source-filtering.html)

I create an index:

```
put testindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "properties":{
        "name": { "type": "text"  },
        "age": { "type": "integer" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

insert a document:

```
put testindex/type1/a
{
  "name":"toto",
  "age":23
}
```

and try a filtered query:

```
get testindex/_search
{
  "_source": {
        "excludes": [ "age" ]
    },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

the result is:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "testindex",
    "_type": "type1",
    "_id": "a",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "name": "toto",
      "age": 23
    }
  }
]
```

I don't understand why it does not hide the "age" field in _source.
_source: false give the same result.
I used elasticsearch & kibana 5.6

Comment: The exact queries work for me in ES 6.0 (as in, `age` field is hidden). I don't use Kibana, but is Kibana relevant here?

Comment: Kibana is not relevant. Works for me on ES 5.6.0

Comment: Which client are you using? What if you use POST instead of GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it.
It's probably due to Kibana.
When I use lowercase for the "get". It does not work.

```
get testindex/_search
{
  "_source": {
        "excludes": [ "age" ]
    },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```

When I use uppercase, it work. I don't really know why but that's it..

```
GET testindex/_search
{ 
  "_source": {
        "excludes": [ "name" ]
    },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": []
    }
  }
}
```